# Numpy equivalents of Ruby array functions

Tags: python, ruby, numpy

I'm working on an assignment to practice data preprocessing, equal width binning in this case, but I'm not familiar with these numpy functions, so my python code is kinda ugly:

```
def eq_width_bin(data, bins):
  bin_edge = np.linspace(np.min(data), np.max(data), bins+1)
  bin_edge[-1] += 1
  re  = []
  for i in data:
    for j in bin_edge:
      if i < j:
        re.append(int(np.argwhere(bin_edge==j))-1)
        break
  return re

data = np.array([80, 95, 70, 30, 20, 10, 75, 65, 98, 103, 130, 70])
print("After equal width binning:\n{}".format(eq_width_bin(data, 3)))
```

however in ruby I can do it with less than 10 lines (despite the fact this is kinda slow):

```
def eq_width_bin(data, bins)
  bin_edge = bins.times.collect{|i| data.min + (data.max - data.min) / bins * i} << data.max + 1
  return data.collect{|i| bin_edge.index{|j| i < j} - 1}
end
data = [80, 95, 70, 30, 20, 10, 75, 65, 98, 103, 130, 70]
puts "After equal width binning:\n#{eq_width_bin(data, 3)}"
```

I often use `.select` `.collect` `.inject` `.sort_by` to dealing with array in ruby, so is there any numpy functions I can use to "beautify" my python code above? (Especially knowing that numpy's built-in functions are way much faster than doing it in pyhton)

Comment: I don't know Numpy, but maybe it would help if you knew the "traditional" names of those operations, since the Ruby names are derived from Smalltalk, where they were named for a little bit of wordplay (collect, inject, detect, select, reject): `select` is commonly called `filter`, `collect` is `map` (or `transform` in C++), `inject` is `reduce` or `fold` (some communities also call it `aggregate` or `accumulate`). Also, `collect` is a special kind of *catamorphism*. Maybe these terms will help you find what you are looking for.

Comment: Hmm … I just saw that `find` is called `extract` in Numpy, so it doesn't look like they use the traditional names either.

Comment: Python lists and iterators (as in `itertools`) has functions along this line.  But this isn't how `numpy` works.   Iterating through a `numpy` array like this is slow.  But `np.bincount` might meet your needs.

Comment: The Ruby code is faster when you start with `min, max = data.minmax` and use those min and max values .`bin_edge = bins.times.collect{|i| min + (max - min) / bins * i} << max + 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially this looked like a `bincount` or `histogram`, but the output is the bins where each value fits, not the number of items per bin:

```
In [3]: eq_width_bin(data,3)                                                    
Out[3]: [1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1]
```

Your bins:

```
In [10]: np.linspace(np.min(data),np.max(data),4)                               
Out[10]: array([ 10.,  50.,  90., 130.])
```

we can identify the bin for each value with a simple integer division:

```
In [12]: (data-10)//40                                                          
Out[12]: array([1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1])
```

and correct that 3 with:

```
In [16]: np.minimum((data-10)//40,2)                                            
Out[16]: array([1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1])
```

But that doesn't answer you question about `.select .collect .inject .sort_by`.  Off hand I'm not familiar with those (though I was a fan of `Squeak` years ago, and dabbled in `Ruby` a bit).  They sound more like iterators, such as those collected in `itertools`.

With `numpy` we don't usually take an iterative approach.  Rather we try to look at the arrays as a whole, doing things like division and min/max for the whole thing.

===

`searchsorted` also works for this problem:

```
In [19]: np.searchsorted(Out[10],data)                                              
Out[19]: array([2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2])

In [21]: np.maximum(0,np.searchsorted(Out[10],data)-1)                              
Out[21]: array([1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1])
```

A (possibly) cleaner expression of your Python loop:

```
def foo(i, edges):
    for j,n in enumerate(edges):
        if i<n:
            return j-1
    return j-1
In [34]: edges = np.linspace(np.min(data),np.max(data),4).tolist()              
In [35]: [foo(i,edges) for i in data]                                           
Out[35]: [1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1]
```

I converted `edges` to a list, because it's faster to iterate that way.

With `itertools`:

```
In [55]: [len(list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x<i,edges)))-1 for i in data]  
Out[55]: [1, 2, 1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1]
```

===

Another approach

```
In [45]: edges = np.linspace(np.min(data),np.max(data),4)                       
In [46]: data[:,None]<-edges                                                    
Out[46]: 
array([[False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False]])
In [47]: np.argmax(data[:,None]<edges, axis=1)-1                                
Out[47]: array([ 1,  2,  1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  2,  2, -1,  1])
```

That `-1` needs cleaning (the row where there's no True).

### edit

Lists have an `index` method; with that we can get an expression that's a lot like your last `Ruby` line.  Looks like list comprehension is a lot like the Ruby `collect`:

```
In [88]: [[i<j for i in edges].index(False)-1 for j in data]                    
Out[88]: [1, 2, 1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1]
```

Comment: thanks for the help and the interesting approaches! And I should start thinking about other non-interactive solutions as you said